# Missing axis in Hightcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How do I manage to see the 8th axis *(called 'aufgabenorientiert')* in my chart?

http://jsfiddle.net/7k8wY/3/

I tried to manage that with:

```
series: [{
    name: 'User',
    data: [[0, 29], [2, 25], [4, 24], [6, 22]],
    pointPlacement: 'on'
}]
```

any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your code should looks like this:

```
$(function () {

$('#container').highcharts({

   chart: {
       renderTo: 'disg_model',
       polar: true,
       type: 'line'
   },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Dominant', 'extrovertiert', 'Initiativ', 'menschen-orientiert', 'Stetig', 'introvertiert', 'Gewissenhaft', 'aufgabenorientiert', ''],
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        lineWidth: 0,
        showEmpty: true,
        showLastLabel: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>'
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 100,
        layout: 'vertical'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Reto Strub',
        data: [[0, 29], [2, 25], [4, 24], [6, 22], [7, 22], [6, 22]],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }]


});
});
```

This is the other way, with no aditional point:

```
 series: [{
        name: 'Reto Strub',
        data: [[0, 29], [2, 25], [4, 24], [7, 22]],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }]
```

You have 7 categories, so one of the serie point should be 7 too...i hope you understand :)

This way the missing one it's showing...have in count the number of categories and the number of vertix on your poligon ;)

Saludos.

Comment: the problem in this solution is, that there is an additional point in the chart

Comment: It should be done this way...or this other way...but the number of categories should be the same...i'm editing the code